# Looping through element attributes and displaying their value with JQuery to make automatic tooltips

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create tooltips with the value of the tooltip pulled from the id attribute of each element. I have the first one firing off but I cannot get how to make the function continue to the next element matching the `$("ul li)"` in the test case below.

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello SO</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <ul>
        <li id="label-1">1</li>
        <li id="label-2">2</li>
        <li id="label-3">3</li>
        <li id="label-4">4</li>
     </ul>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function(){
        var LabelData = $("ul li").attr("id");
        var LabelContainer = $("li");
            LabelContainer.html('Label Name:'+LabelData);
        });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

[And... heres the fiddle]

Comment: You forgot the fiddle

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $("ul li").each(function(){
    var LabelData = $(this).attr("id");
    var LabelContainer = $(this);
    LabelContainer.html('Label Name:'+LabelData);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goal using following code snippet:

```
 $(function(){
        $("ul li").each(function(){
            $(this).html($(this).attr('id'));
 });
```

Here is **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cDmH9/4/)**.